# Abstract method for subclass "student" and "lecturer"

Tags: java, methods, abstract

I have received a Java assignment recently. The assignment is making a project about education. So, I decided to make a class about University which has 2 sub- classes "student" and "lecturer". Now, I have a problem with the abstract method. My Prof. said abstract method must be for all sub-classes. Hence, the problem that I am facing now. I do not know what abstract method that can be implemented for subclass "student" and "lecturer". Any suggestions?

#juniorCoder
#new2Java

Comment: What exactly were the tasks in this assignment? Do you have to model a university? *The assignment is making a project about education* is far too unclear... Is your question just about how to use an `abstract class Person` that is extended by a `Lecturer` and a `Student`? If yes, they will have some common attributes, like a name, an age, a nationality and so on. An `abstract` method you could provide is a getter for the name: `public String getName()`, for example. A method `public double getGrade()` should not be made abstract because a `Student` may have grades, but a `Lecturer` won't.

Comment: The assignment is about the registration of a University that registers lecturers and students. The super class is University which has attributes such as UniName, UniCode, etc. And the sub-classes have similar attribute as well such as Name, Age, ID, etc. My Prof wants my group to make a method besides the getter method. In other words, my Prof wants a processor  method that is abstract  that can be used for both sub-classes. Hope this sounds clearer. TQ

Comment: your comment clarifies a lot, that is good. Please keep in mind that you can and should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53613827/edit) in order to add information instead of posting another comment, thank you. I will have a look at your problem soon, hopefully many other will do so, too.

Comment: What class should be the `abstract` one? `University` or a super class for the persons involved (student and lecturer)? **Do not create an `abstract class University` in combination with `class Lecturer extends University`** because that would be just the wrong way to model the situation (an institution *has* persons working / learning there but a person *is no* institution).

Comment: My idea is, the University class(super class) is the abstract class. While the sub-classes, "Student" and "Lecturer extends  University.

Comment: If you do it like that, then `Students` and `Lecturers` will also be of type `University`, in terms of content they will be universities. That would then be wrong in terms of content...

Comment: Well, what would you suggest? Honestly, I am thinking of quitting this project. It would seem that I have started this project incorrectly. Plus my misunderstanding on the inheritance concept

Comment: No need for quitting... Do you know how to model a UML class diagram? Otherwise think of how it is in reality: A university is an educational institution where lecturers work and students get educated (maybe even learn something). The relation between university and lecturers respectively students is not "is a" but "has a", like "a university has lecturers". That seems to me like a class `University` having an attribute of type `List<Lecturer>`. Both, lecturers and students are persons and so both of them might be inheriting from an `abstract class Person`. Think this way...

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. The wifi in my university somehow went down for a few hours. Yes i know how to model a UML class diagram, but I hardly did one this semester since it is not required in our syllabus. i discussed with my group mates, and we had an idea for an abstract method for both "student" and "lecturer". That is to find the rating of the university depending on how many lecturers have PhD's and how many students graduated with a high CGPA.

Comment: So, in the main program, to see what rating that university gets, is by calling both of the methods. I picture it as 
Rating based on Lecturer : 5 stars
Rating based on Student : 4 stars

Comment: A rating system, ok... I think you should model a class diagram and discuss that (and maybe show it here in your question by edit).

Answer (score 0):

"Student" and "Lecturer" are bad example of inheritance because it should be connected with 'IS A' construction. For example:

```
class Phone { }
class IPhone extend Phone {}
```

`IPhone` IS A `Phone` that exactly match inheritance idea.
In your case `Student` is NOT a `University`

So I can suggest make another subclasses of `University`. For instance some concrete University. It would be easier then to come up abstract methods.

```
abstract class University {
    abstract String getLocation(); // get location of concrete universtity
}
class MIT extends University {
    @Override
    public String getLocation() {
        return "Cambridge, MA USA";
    }
}
class Standford extends University {
    @Override
    public String getLocation() {
        return "450 Serra Mall, Stanford, CA 94305, USA";
    }
}
```

You can also add any methods that would be applied to each university like a `getRating()`, `getDescription()` etc.

Comment: Your statement, "In your case Student is NOT a University" has open my eyes that  I have made a mistake for choosing Student and Lecturer as sub-classes for University. Strange how my Prof. did not say anything about this idea.

This is an interesting and proper example for overcoming my problem. May i ask some instance variables that can be implemented for the sub-classes?

For instance, MIT as the subclass for University, is it valid for me to make number of available space for students and lecturers as the instance variable?

Comment: The idea on getRating(),can i calculate how many lecturers who are PhD holders for that university. If the number of PhD holders are, lets say more than 20, then the rating for that university would be 2 or 3 stars. Something like that. What do you think?

Comment: @KamarulAdha Yes you can calculate rating as you want. It would be your own implementation of rating calculation.

Comment: @KamarulAdha you can add instance variables like you said. Also rating can be implemented as variable too, because it can be changed (in your case it depends on how many lecturers are PhD holders)